# Как выровнять элементы таблицы по горизонтали?

Tags: css

Свойство text-align не работает

```
.pagiNav
{
    text-align: center;
}


.paginActive
{
    background: url(../graphic/elements/pactempty.png) no-repeat;

}
.paginAnother
{
    background: url(../graphic/elements/pempty.png) no-repeat;

}

.paginActive, .paginAnother
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 42px;
    height: 36px;

    line-height: 33px;
}

.paginAnother
{
    color: #26A313;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.paginFirst
{
    background-image: url(../graphic/elements/pleft.png);
}

.paginLast
{
    background-image: url(../graphic/elements/pright.png);
}
.paginFirst, .paginLast
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="pagiNav">


    <?php if ($pagination->first_page() !== false): ?>
        <!--Ссылка перехода, на первую страницу-->
        <a href="<?= Url::super_url(['pagin' => $pagination->first_page()]) ?>" class="paginFirst"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>





    <?php foreach ($pagination->nav() as $page): ?>

        <?php if ($page == $pagination->get_page()): ?>
            <!--Активная страница в данный момент-->
            <span class="paginActive tac small"><?= $page+10000 ?></span>

        <?php else: ?>
            <!--Ссылка на другие страницы-->
            <a href="<?= Url::super_url(['pagin' => $page]) ?>" class="tac paginAnother small"><?= $page ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>




    <?php if ($pagination->latest_page() !== false): ?>
        <!--Ссылка перехода, на последнюю страницу-->
        <a href="<?= Url::super_url(['pagin' => $pagination->latest_page()]) ?>" class="paginLast"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>




</div>
```

Comment: Саму таблицу и css хотя бы добавьте для наглядности

Comment: добавил ываьруыпоаыо

Comment: добавил ываьруыпоаыо

Comment: А html таблицы?

Comment: Просто скажи как можно выровнять элементы table-cell в элементе table по горизонтали

Comment: Как кто-то может понять в чем причина, не видя самого источника причины (в вашем случае - разметки таблицы)?

Answer (score 0):

Уже решил. Свойство `text-align` с таблицей походу не работает. Использовал `margin: 0 auto`